# Save or add QgsVectorLayer object feature in a layer that is already created

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

After getting the QgsVectorLayer `result`, I want to save its features in a layer named `dimensioning`, that is already created. How to do it in PyQGIS?

`result = processing.run("qgis:explodelines", {'INPUT':temp_lines,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})["OUTPUT"]`

Comment: Another option is to use a Processing algorithm to copy&paste the features. The algorithm is called 'Append features to layer', installed by the `AppendFeaturesToLayer` plugin. See https://github.com/gacarrillor/AppendFeaturesToLayer/ for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Your layer named dimensioning
layer_dimensioning = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("dimensioning")[0]
# Provider in order to access your layer features
provider_layer_dimensioning = layer_dimensioning.dataProvider()

result = processing.run("qgis:explodelines", {'INPUT':temp_lines,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})["OUTPUT"]

# Start edition
layer_dimensioning.startEditing()

# Loop on the features of the layer result
# Addition of each feature in layer dimensioning
for feature in result.getFeatures():
    provider_layer_dimensioning.addFeature(feature)

# Save the changes
layer_dimensioning.commitChanges()
```